# What is the approach to use instead of multiple inheritance in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

As is known TypeScript does not support multiple inheritance.

What is approach to use instead, definitely it can be composition. Also to apply builder pattern?

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance, hence there's no approach to do it. If you have a specific problem, post the specific problem along with code. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: What approach would you use in JavaScript? I would imagine that question has the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. Its main purpose is to provide type savety as JavaScript itself doesn‘t care about this issue.

JavaScript is incomparable to C++, C# or Java when it comes to inheritance.

To sum it up: Yes, composition is the better way to go here.